# How to make consecutive key or index in java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, data-structures

I have two list index in order integer who initialize with ***id1*** and the second index is ***id2***. Both index have key/number of integer such as below:

> id1 =  ***1,1,1,2,2,3***
>
> id2 = ***2,3,4,3,4,4***

and I want to sort both index to

> Index ***1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4***

How can i reach it ?

Here's my code:

```
    int d = list.size();

    int index = 0;                 

    List<Double> listM = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> data = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();

    for (int id1 = 0; id1 < d - 1; id1++) {
            for (int id2 = id1 + 1; d2 < id; d2++) {

                 if (!data.containsKey(d1)) {
                    data.put(d1, new HashSet<Integer>());
                    }
                    data.get(d1).add(index);

                 if (!data.containsKey(d2)) {
                    data.put(d2, new HashSet<Integer>());
                 }
                 data.get(d2).add(index2);

            }

     }

     int cc = 0;
     for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
         int maxIndex = 0;
         double maxScore = Double.MIN_VALUE;

         for (Integer index : entry.getValue()) {
             Double score = listM3.get(cc);                   

             if (score > maxScore) {
                 maxScore = score;
                 maxIndex = index;
             }
             cc++;
         }
     }
```

and the result is

> ***1,2,1,3,1,4,2,3,2,4,3,4,4***

Any answer will be appreciated , Thanks .

Comment: `list.addAll(id1);` `list.addAll(id2);` `Collections.sort(list);`

Comment: How about if id1 is integer not list ?

Comment: @PutraNurfajar you mean integer array?

Comment: are all your numbers in the variable `list`?

Comment: @BOND no, it means variable integer not array for example such above `int index = 0;`

Comment: Why do we need a map to combine two lists and sort them?

Comment: @gonzo yes . it's two list who combine and sort them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this taking advantage of `Collections.sort` and `List.addAll`.

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> combinedSortedList = new ArrayList<>();
combinedSortedList.addAll(list1);  //Add list1 to our new sorted list
combinedSortedList.addAll(list2); //Add list2 to our new sorted list
Collections.sort(combinedSortedList); //Sorts the list for you
```

Comment: Thanks gonzo for answer, I'll try it and back again soon . .